# Работа с websocket в Spring

Tags: java, spring, websocket

Здравствуйте, мой вопрос заключается в следующем: у меня есть чат, реализованный с помощью javax.websocket, мне захотелось переделать его на Spring, однако в Spring я силен не сильно, поэтому пока Spring websocket использовать не стал и оставил реализацию на javax.websocket. Теперь, в случае есть я собираю проект и деплою его в Tomcat 9, у меня все хорошо работает, однако если деплоить его в Tomcat встроенный в Spring, то вылетает ошибка

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5050//echo?username=;123' failed:


Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Здесь я ради примера передаю имя пользователя сразу в запросе.
Я читал, что для реализации надо указать бин в конфигах от спринг, но сделать ничего не смог толком. Вот и мой вопрос, как реализовать работу, если это возможно?
Оставлю части кода с моей реализацией.
Сервер:

```
@ServerEndpoint(
        value = "/echo"
)
public class ServerSocket {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config) throws IOException {}
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, String message) throws IOException {}
```

Клиент:

```
 connectClient("ws://" + document.location.host + document.location.pathname + "/echo?username=" + document.getElementById("annoyInput").value);

function connectClient(URL) {
        webSocket = new WebSocket(URL);}
```

Готов предоставить любые куски кода) 
В целом, кроме сокетов, все работает, все файлы из static открываются, я не использую themeliaf поэтому они все там.

Comment: попробуйте начать с руководства https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/, а потом переделать свой пример по образу и подобию

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, хорошо, мне тоже все кажется, что лучше выбрать что-то одно, чем городить огород из нескольких фреймворков, попробую тогда реализовать с помощью Spring

Comment: @MikhailVaysman , нашел все таки в документации, что можно сделать и без Spring websocket, однако, это уже после того, как все переделал, так что еще раз, большое спасибо)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Сделал с помощью Spring websocket, воспользовавшись ссылкой из первого комментария под вопросом, могу теперь полностью отказаться от javax и перейти на полноценный Spring проект. Проблему, описанную выше не решил.

Comment: Стоит добавить описание самого решения в ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy , простите, ввел в заблуждение скорее всего тем, что пространно написал ответ, старую логику я не восстановил, просто добавил логику из примера, не более, подумал, что переписывать пример сюда будет неправильно, теперь буду думать над тем, как восстановить старую